# Robot is printing same string multiple times from clipboard

Tags: java, awt, clipboard

I have written a function a print a string by Robot class. But when I am calling the function multiple times, each time it is printing the last string. Following is my code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class ForTesting {
private static void typeInModalWindow(String stringToBeTyped) throws AWTException{
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(stringToBeTyped);
    System.out.println("String recevied :: "+stringToBeTyped);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection,null);
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection,stringSelection);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
  }

public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
    typeInModalWindow("USER");
    typeInModalWindow("PASS");
    typeInModalWindow("another");
    //anotheranotheranother
  }
}
```

To teet it, before executing i have kept my cursor in the last comment section in my code, so the result is printed there.

Comment: `"...each time it is printing the last string"` -- please show us what you mean by this. What output are you getting? and where?

Comment: @hovercraft Please see the last line in my code, before executing i have kept my cursor there, so it printed there.

Comment: You may need to slow the code's running a bit, since the non-Robot code will run instantaneously while the Robot portion will have a delay. The delay is enough for only the last String to be on the clipboard.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That worked, I added `Thread.sleep(500)` in between the calls.